# Change plotly html plot title in browser tab

Tags: r, plotly

I use `plotly` to visualize my data by saving it as an `html` widget and open it in the browser as I find the native viewer to be quite slow.

**CODE FOR OFFLINE PLOT**

```
library(plotly)
libraray(htmlwidgets)

offlinePlot <- function(pname, fname, browse = T){
 saveWidget(as_widget(x = pname), file = fname)
 if(browse){
 browseURL(fname)
 }
}

offlinePlot(pname = sampleplot, fname = sampleplot.html, browse = T)
```

Generally, I have a few plots open in the browser at the same time and they render fine but all plots have the same title in the browser tabs, is there a way to change this and set the tab title to something custom?

There was a post on something similar linking to this page: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/plot_api/plot_config.js but I don't quite get it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the title for the tab in `htmlwidgets::saveWidget` by adding `title` argument

```
library(plotly)

x <- c(1:100)
random_y <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
data <- data.frame(x, random_y)

p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~random_y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')


htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(p), "graph.html",title = "my title")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! who knew it would be that simple :) On a side note, do you know of any ways besides `orca` to save a `plotly` plot as a pdf or eps file?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that. If you are having issues with it, probably it's better to ask a new question.

Comment: I wonder how one may accomplish the same using the standard viewer, from python code. All the python docs mention in this regard seems to be an argument documented as "A dict of parameters to configure the figure. The defaults are set in plotly.js." It would be nice to have the tab named same as the chart's title, when launching a chart (`.show()`) from plotly express python code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hack that handles setting the browser title from python.  First create a file called `titlerenderer.py` and include the code below:

```py
from plotly.io._base_renderers import BrowserRenderer, open_html_in_browser
from plotly.io._renderers import renderers


class TitleBrowserRenderer(BrowserRenderer):
    def __init__(
        self,
        config=None,
        auto_play=False,
        using=None,
        new=0,
        autoraise=True,
        post_script=None,
        animation_opts=None,
    ):
        super().__init__(
            config, auto_play, using, new, autoraise, post_script, animation_opts
        )

    browser_tab_title = "Undefined"

    def render(self, fig_dict):
        from plotly.io import to_html

        html = (
            """
<title>
"""
            + self.browser_tab_title
            + """
</title>
"""
            + to_html(
                fig_dict,
                config=self.config,
                auto_play=self.auto_play,
                include_plotlyjs=True,
                include_mathjax="cdn",
                post_script=self.post_script,
                full_html=True,
                animation_opts=self.animation_opts,
                default_width="100%",
                default_height="100%",
                validate=False,
            )
        )
        open_html_in_browser(html, self.using, self.new, self.autoraise)


renderers["titleBrowser"] = TitleBrowserRenderer()
```

Then in your plotly.express code, use:

```py
import titlereader   # Needed to hook in the renderer

# Create your figure

fig.show(renderer="titleBrowser", browser_tab_title="MY TITLE")
```

No guarantees that this is robust, but it worked for my use case!