# Altering browser tab name to reflect plotly output

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

```
df = df.set_index(['Date'])  #set index on date

fig = px.pie(df.loc['2022-1-1':'2022-12-31'], values="Payment", names="ExpenseType", title="Household Expenses 2022")
fig.show()
```

Currently, each Plotly output is shown in the browser with a tab name of my local host IP. Instead, I would like the browser tab to be the report title "Household Expenses 2022".

Does Plotly offer this type of control?

Thanks, Dan

Comment: Try to read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73807264/16733101

Comment: Looks like it works...but.  I now get the text i want in the browser tab, followed by my localhost IP.  I can live with that.  Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change plotly html plot title in browser tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57222477/change-plotly-html-plot-title-in-browser-tab)

Comment: It did not.  Errors raised for htmlwidgets. htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(p), "graph.html",title = "my title")
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I am satisfied with the example provided in stackoverflow.com/a/73807264/16733101   Thank you